# Error setting image from url in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, swift4, alamofireimage

My server returns 2 types of images (blob, jpg), I am using alamofireImage and when I set an image type blob

```
(http://example.com/images/img_cars/2018_04_09509414.blob)
iv_car.af_setImage(withURL: url_blobImage)
```

the image does not appear. But When I set an image type jpg

```
(http://example.com/images/img_trucks/2018_04_09825018.JPG)
iv_truck.af_setImage(withURL: url_blobImage)
```

the image appears, How can I solve that problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: can you give the link of blob image?

Comment: the main thing we don't know is what the image format of your .blob is -- it may be that UIImage doesn't understand it and that it needs to be converted.

Comment: before if it worked, but not now, and I have not changed anything

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S is in my localhost

Comment: @Dimoreno, You can solve your problem, if you upload your image on drive and get the public link to post here